# Z-index not hiding background

Tags: css

I am trying to over lap a div on another div  by using css, while background should become blur,  like modal pop up show.

But the background of modal pop is still getting displayed through the modal pop up.

[image]

As u can see background is visible through the modal pop up!!
I have setted z-index of pop up more than the background

CSS:

```
       .MoreDetails
{

  background-color: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display:   block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;


   }

.tblView
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity: 2.0;

}
```

My design:

```
     <div id="MoreDetails" class="MoreDetails" >

           <div id="tableDetails" class="tblView">

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child element cannot be stacked below parent element, even by using `z-index`.

Use `z-index` for maintaining stack level of absolute positioned elements that are siblings.

http://jsfiddle.net/TWLgc/

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

 <div id="MoreDetails" class="MoreDetails" >
<div id="tableDetails" class="tblView">

</div>             
</div>

<div id="tableDetails2" class="tblView2">

</div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.MoreDetails
{

  /*background-color: #000;*/
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  display:   block;
  /*opacity: 0.7;*/
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

.tblView
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 30%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity: 1;

    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.tblView2
{
    position: fixed;
    margin:auto;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    z-index: 101;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue is that you're nesting the `tableDetails` inside the `MoreDetails` div. Any `opacity` or `z-index` you apply to `tableDetails` will affect `MoreDetails`. Another approach might be to use the `::before` pseudo class on `tableDetails` and position the two with CSS.

Some other tips:

- Don't share id and class names. Using `MoreDetails` as both an id and
  a class may end up breaking things as you progress.
- `opacity` can
  only have a value from 0 - 1.

Hope this helps! Good luck!